# why should we write props in curly braces while using in child component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

While passing prop as an argument in Person(Child Component) function why we should write props in curly braces?

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Person from './Person';

const App = () => {
  return (
  <div>
     <Person name={"John"} /> 
  </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

Person.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Person = ({name}) => {       //I am talking about this line
  return (
  <div>
     <h1/>My name is {name}.</h1>
  </div>
);
}

export default Person;
```

Comment: It's just the object destructuring syntax. Also this is the reason why you should learn the fundamentals before jumping into learning the framework or library which my colleague and I were having an argument about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the string prop to be passed down is static - as it is here - there's no need to.

```
<Person name="John" />
```

will work just fine.

You need `{}`s whenever the value to be passed down *isn't* static - for example, when it comes from a variable:

```
<Person name={nameFromState} />
```

You also need `{}`s when interpolating anything into JSX (outside of props), as you see in

```
<h1/>My name is {name}.</h1>
```

This line

```
const Person = ({name}) => {
```

is just destructuring, which is equivalent to

```
const Person = (props) => {
  const { name } = props;
```

which is equivalent to

```
const Person = (props) => {
  const name = props.name;
```

All of those possibilities work just fine, but some prefer to destructure in the argument list to make things more concise.

Comment: It's not what the question was asking. The OP was asking about the line `const Person = ({name}) => {`

Comment: So I assume it must be good for only if you have one prop value ?

Comment: @ShubhamSinghvi It's a style choice. Personally, I prefer to always destructure props (no nested destructuring though), regardless of how many there are.

Answer (score -1):

Use `{}` to use javascript inside JSX by wrapping it in curly braces. You can read more in the docs `reactjs`: https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx