# in next.js how will i access data in object

Tags: next.js

here is my object
[image]

here is my todolist component where i want to pass TODO OBJECT

[image]

HERE IS MY COMPONENT WHERE I WANT TO RECIEVE THE DATA NAME IN OBJECT

[image]

how can get todo name in my todo component? it is giving error

Comment: You can access the passed value via `props`, this might help you https://codesandbox.io/s/passing-props-in-functional-comp-x5tvho?file=/src/Thread.js

Comment: Can you add your code instead of screenshots?

Comment: done just a side question what is the difference between export default function Thread(props) and export default function Thread({props})?

Comment: the first one i pass the complete prop

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69060257/why-should-we-write-props-in-curly-braces-while-using-in-child-component This can answer you

Answer (score 0):

You should do `todo.name` in place of `todo.todos.name`